# SSHing into system with ZSH as default shell doesn't run /etc/profile

Tags: shell, zsh, login, profile, dot-files

I'm experiencing a strange behavior on some of our machines atm. At least, it seems strange to me and my colleagues and we didn't find any explanation for it :)

[edit 1]
**Next paragraph seems to be wrong. See edit 2 at end.**
<strike>We're using bash and zsh here. So, when SSHing into some of the zsh-default-machines (plain `ssh login@host`) which are configured to use zsh as default shell (with `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh`), the then-opened shell is an interactive but **non-login** shell, regardless if we're already logged in on the respective machine or not.</strike>

In my understanding, SSHing into a machine should be starting a new user session on that machine, thus requiring the shell to be a login shell, right? Shouldn't that be the case for zsh, too?

When changing the default shell to bash on the machines, logging into the machine uses a login-shell.

Is this the normal behavior for zsh? Could it be changed? Or is it some misconfiguration?
[/edit 1]

[edit 2]
Ok, according to the ZSH documentation you could easily test if it is a login shell or not:

```bsh
$ if [[ -o login ]]; then; print yes; else; print no; fi
```

See: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html

However, due to zsh man entry / documentation, zsh should source `/etc/profile` which in turn sources the scripts under `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`. My question above originated in the fact, that the scripts are **not** sourced and thus most of our environment variables and system configuration stuff isn't properly initialized. However, as described above - when we're using bash as default shell, `/etc/profile` and the scripts in the profile.d-folder are sourced.
[/edit 2]

[edit 3 - ANSWER]
Thx @StéphaneChazelas for the answer in the comments below!
It seems `zsh` is only sourcing `/etc/profile` when running in `sh`/`ksh` compatibility mode (see the respecitve man entry https://linux.die.net/man/1/zsh). 
As logging in via SSH doesn't trigger that compatibility mode, `zsh` doesn't necessarily source `/etc/profile` on it's own but have to be triggered via `.zprofile`
[/edit 3]

System: 
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
zsh-5.4.2 with omz and some plugins activated.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you testing whether it's a login shell or not?

Comment: how did you infer that zsh is not a login shell? Afaik a zsh login shell will not source `~/.profile` but `~/.zprofile`.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $options[login] $0 $SHLVL` in the interactive shell you get upon `ssh login@host`?

Comment: @mosvy, also `~/.zlogin` (à la csh)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas
Output is `on -zsh 1`

Anyway, I tried `if [[ -o login ]]; then; print yes; else; print no; fi` from the zsh manual, which showed me that in fact *is* a login shell. So, my fault. Sorry.

But then, why are the scripts in `/etc/profile.d` are not sourced when logged in via ssh? According to the zsh man entry, `/etc/profile` should be parsed when logging into a login-shell? Any idea?

Comment: `/etc/profile` is only sourced when `zsh` is invoked in `sh` or `ksh` emulation or if `/etc/zsh/zprofile` sources it. Remember the syntax of `zsh` is different from that of other Bourne-like shells, so you may need to check that the syntax of /etc/profile is compatible with that of zsh or make sure /etc/profile is sourced in `sh` emulation if you consider doing it from `/etc/zsh/zprofile` (something like `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas
Oh, that was fast - thx!

I wasn't aware that `zsh` is only sourcing `/etc/profile` when in `sh/ksh` emulation mode...to be honest, I just heard from the emulation mode for the first time :) must have skipped the respective paragraphs in the `zsh` man entry before...

Maybe you could write an answer I could accept it...?

Comment: This site has an edit history.  Don’t leave all that struck through text, it’s ugly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ZSH just works in this way. **`/etc/profile` is NOT an init file for ZSH**. ZSH uses `/etc/zprofile` and `~/.zprofile`.

Init files for ZSH:

1. `/etc/zshenv`
2. `~/.zshenv`
3. login mode:

   1. `/etc/zprofile`
   2. `~/.zprofile`
4. interactive:

   1. `/etc/zshrc`
   2. `~/.zshrc`
5. login mode:

   1. `/etc/zlogin`
   2. `~/.zlogin`

[image]

Tips:

- Default shell opened in your terminal on Linux is a non-login, interactive shell. But on macOS, it's a login shell.

References

- [Unix shell initialization](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization#zsh)
- [Shell Startup Scripts](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the flowchart and the informative links!

Comment: In my `.zprofile` I have `export TEST="hello"`. But when I do `echo $TEST` it returns empty string, is it normal behavior?

Comment: @alper If you're on Linux, that's the normal behavior.  Because the default shell opened in your terminal on Linux is a non-login shell. But on macOS, it's a login shell.

Comment: I am in Linux but on a remote machine that is connected via ssh. I was advices to carry all my export variables into `.zprofile` but when I did that they all return empth string and all are empty

Answer (score 7):

`sshd` runs a login shell when the client doesn't send any command to run. That's to mimic the behaviour of `rsh` which was calling the `rlogind` service instead of the `rshd` one when not given any command to run.

To tell the shell it is to be a login shell, like `rlogind` or `login` or `telnetd`, `sshd` starts your shell with an `argv[0]` that starts with a `-`.

Or course, `zsh` like every other shell understands it as well. If it didn't, it couldn't ever be invoked in *login* mode.

Here, the symptom that made you think you didn't get a login shell was because `/etc/profile` was not interpreted.

`/etc/profile` is the login session initialisation file for Bourne-like shells. Syntax in there is expected to be in the Bourne shell syntax (or possibly POSIX sh syntax as the Bourne shell is hardly ever used these days) and is read upon login by all the shells whose syntax is (mostly) backward compatible with the Bourne or POSIX sh syntax.

`csh` and `tcsh` which have a completely different syntax use `/etc/csh.login` instead. `fish` uses `/etc/fish/config.fish` (regardless of whether it's in login mode or not).

`zsh`'s syntax is also not completely compatible with that of Bourne/POSIX, so by default, it doesn't read `/etc/profile`. Its configuration files in login mode are `/etc/zsh/zprofile` (or `/etc/zprofile` depending on how `zsh` was configured at build time) and `/etc/zsh/zlogin` (or `/etc/zlogin`) the latter being sourced after the `zshrc`.

`zsh` only sources `/etc/profile` when in `sh` or `ksh` emulation in which case its syntax is much closer to that of POSIX sh than in the default `zsh` emulation mode.

If you want `zsh` to source `/etc/profile` when in login mode, you'd need to add a `source /etc/profile` in `/etc/zsh/zprofile`, but you'd only want to do that when you have made sure the syntax of `/etc/profile` and any other file it sources is compatible with that of `zsh`.

Alternatively, you could add:

```
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'
```

To `/etc/zsh/zprofile`. Then `/etc/profile` would be sourced in `sh` emulation mode (and functions declared in there would also retain the `sh` emulation mode).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! :)

Comment: Ok, one more question out of curiosity ;)
Do you also know why `/etc/profile` *is* sourced when opening a non-login shell (with terminator, xterm ...)?

Comment: @nightsparc, sourced by what shell? Note that some terminal emulators can be configured to start a login shell and some systems configure them like that by default.

Comment: Sourced by `zsh`...maybe it's an Ubuntu (or Debian?) thing? `/etc/profile` is sourced whenever I'm starting a terminal emulator, regardless which one I'm using (I tried `gnome-terminal`, `xterm` uand `terminator`). Thats confusing, from your explanation above I'd assume that `/etc/profile[.d]` is only sourced when `zsh`is forced to use the compatibility mode. Or, according to `man zsh` when it is  invoked as `sh` or `ksh`...but why are the terminal emulators are invoking it as `sh/ksh`? And is there a way to change it?

Comment: @nightsparc, what makes you think it runs /etc/profile? /etc/profile would probably have been sourced when you logged in. So environment variables would be inherited by the terminal emulator and by the shells started in there.

Comment: Oh, right, of course. How could I not have thought of that :) thanks again!