# Funtoo Keychain keeps asking for password when logging in using SSH

Tags: ssh, zsh, ssh-agent, funtoo, keychain

I have followed the instructions here https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain and added

```
eval `keychain --eval --agents ssh --inherit any id_rsa`
```

to - I have tried both but the result was the same - .zshrc and .zprofile. Now the first terminal that I open requires me to enter the password for the SSH key (as expected) but after that, I never need to enter the password, independently of how many terminals I open.

However, if I log in to this machine using SSH I need to enter the SSH key password every time I connect. Obviously there is some difference how the shell is setup if I open a new terminal session sitting in front of the machine or open an SSH session.

**How do I make SSH logins "inherit" the Funtoo Keychain setup/environment so I don't need to enter the password for the SSH key every time I log in to this machine using SSH?**

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537637/sshing-into-system-with-zsh-as-default-shell-doesnt-run-etc-profile have you checked if it runs as a login shell? `if [[ -o login ]]; then; print yes; else; print no; fi` it should

Comment: @dza I am not sure I understand how to use the linked Q&A in my situation. Do you think you could elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: use snippet I posted in prev comment and report back if it says yes or no in the term you tried.

Comment: @dza I SSH from A to B. Your snippet returns "yes" on both A and B.

Comment: I just reread question, its been 3 years and now I think I can answer your question.. Look for `${HOME}/.keychain/${HOST}-sh` directory in home.. this is where you can source `source ~/.keychain/hostname-sh` that file and your keychain should be initiated with the `ssh-agent` PID I think, try to read the file.. it sets environment variable..

Comment: @dza I am not followinf you here. The `${HOME}/.keychain/${HOST}-sh` is not a directory, it is a file with this content `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.5fhOwlNPlb/Listeners; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;`. I don't have `~/.keychain/hostname-sh` file. Thank you.

Comment: yes, that file is being made after you typed your password, so all you have to do is `source ${HOME}/.keychain/${HOST}-sh` on the shell you connect after you have authenticated the ssh-key..